# What is this solution of matrices called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I have the solution to a problem here.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 2 & 7 \\
    1 & 1 & 3 \\
    9 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 5 \\
    9 & 1 & 9 \\
    2 & 2 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

That gives a result of

\begin{bmatrix}
    27 & 3 & 74 \\
\end{bmatrix}

What exactly is happening here? Please help! Why isn't the solution a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Comment: welcome to math.SE! You are right, the result should be a $3 \times 3$ matrix. Have you tried to compute the result either by pencil/paper or using Matlab? One of these methods should give you a more correct answer.

Comment: Thank you, it is the MATLAB result for A.B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab, the dot function treats A and B as collections of column vectors.

The first column of A is $\vec{A_1}=(5,1,9)$, the first column of B is $\vec{B_1}=(0,9,2)$, hence the dot product $\vec{A_1}\cdot \vec{B_1}=27$ and so on, giving the total result $A\cdot B =(27, 3, 74)$ **which is NOT the matrix product**

You are probably looking for the operation A*B which gives the **matrix product** of A and B.

Comment: In Matlab, type "**A*B**" to get the 3x3 matrix product

Comment: Thank you! I understand that A*B = matrix product = dot product of the matrices. Could you tell me what my result is called? Does it have some kind of significance?

Comment: @Sheila the product you were using is called *scalar dot product*. In your case, MATLAB computed the dot product of the 1st-2nd-3rd columns of your matrices and collected the results in a vector. More here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html

Comment: @FilippoDeBortoli Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of multiplication is this but when you multiply normally you should get a 3 cross 3 matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 2 & 7 \\
    1 & 1 & 3 \\
    9 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 5 \\
    9 & 1 & 9 \\
    2 & 2 & 6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

They are multiplying the first column of the matrix A with the first column of the matrix B element by element and adding them

Similarly the second column of matrix A with the second column of  matrix B

$$5\cdot0+1\cdot9+9\cdot2=27$$
$$2\cdot1+1\cdot1+0\cdot2=3$$
$$7\cdot5+3\cdot9+2\cdot6=74$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    27 & 3 & 74 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

When you multiply matrix A with matrix B you should get

$$A*B=\begin{bmatrix}
    32 & 21 & 85 \\
    15 & 8 & 32 \\
    4 & 13 & 57 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}
    62 & 21 & 85 \\
    21 & 8 & 32 \\
    58 & 13 & 57 \\
    \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Isn't this the matrix multiplication?

Comment: No probably you made some mistake while calculating the first column

Comment: Thank you! Yes I did.